# How to use didInsertElement properly in ember.js component?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I want to inject thirdparty JS and do some stuff after the component is inserted into the DOM. So the `didInsertElement` hook will be fine for me.

There are following two different types in using the `didInsertElement`.

`initialLoad: on('didInsertElement', function() {});`

And

`didInsertElement() {}`

What is the difference between them? Which one I've to use for my use case? Please guide.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the way to go, refer [Ember components life cycle](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/components/the-component-lifecycle/)

```
didInsertElement() {
 this._super(...arguments);
}
```

The below is the not the right way. reason is it does not follow any order to execute function. suppose if you got two or more functions is subscribed to didInsertElement then you can't ensure the order

```
initialLoad: on('didInsertElement', function() {
});
initialSomeStuff: on('didInsertElement', function() {
});
```

Comment: [The Guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/components/the-component-lifecycle/) refers the first one. (you can add this link to your post). I'd read the second one also has performance issues. (But I've no link.)

Comment: Thanks @kumkanillam